# Let ${a_n}$ be a sequence of real numbers. The backwards differences of this sequence are defined recursively:

Tags: discrete-mathematics, catalan-numbers

Let ${a_n}$ be a sequence of real numbers. The backwards differences of this
sequence are defined recursively:

The first difference $∇a_n$ is an new sequence defined by:$∇a_{n} = a_{n} - a_{n-1} $

The $(k + 1)$st difference $∇^{k+1}a_n $ is $∇^{k+1}a_n = ∇^{k}a_{n} - ∇^{k}a_{n-1}  $ Find $∇a_{n}$ and $∇^{2}a_{n}$ for $a_{n} = 2n$ and $a_{n} = n^2$

So far I have been able to determine (using the first difference formula) that $∇a_n$ for $a_n = 2n$ is as follows...
$$∇a_n = 2n - (2(n-1))$$
$$∇a_n = 2$$
However I have not been able to figure out the $∇^2a_n$ case.
As for the second case I have done the same in figuring out $∇a_n$ but have not been able to get $∇^2a_n$
$∇a_n$ for $a_n = n^2$ is as follows...
$$∇a_n = n^2 - (n-1)^2$$
$$∇a_n = n^2 - n^2 - 2n + 1$$
$$∇a_n = -2n+1$$
Any help with the $∇^2a_n$ cases would be greatly appreciated. The main part I am having trouble understanding how we would get the $∇a_{n-1}$ case to use in the given formula.

Comment: Have you tried anything? It would be good to see what exactly is your question, what you have tried already, etc rather than just stating a problem which seems to be like homework.

Comment: I'm not sure how to proceed because i have never worked with the ∇ operator before, and I am unsure whether it represents a variable or some predefined value.

Comment: You can just use the formula it gives. So applying that operator to $a_n$ gives you $a_n-a_{n-1}$. Put now instead of $a_n$ the sequences you have. For the first one, $a_n=2n$ and $a_{n-1}=2(n-1)$. What do you get? Same for the other one.

Comment: So from what you are saying, applying the first different formula to the $a_n = 2n$ would yield $2n - (2(n-1))$? If this is the case then I am not sure how the $(k+1)^{st}$ difference formula would be needed or used.

Comment: Yes, exactly as you say, and by simplifying you see that the answer is $2$. As for the more general formula, it is given to show you how the operator acts if you apply it more than once. And you need to understand what happens for the second part of the question, which would be for $k=1$ in that formula.

Comment: Oh! I believe I understand now. So for the second part of the question we would apply the (k+1) formula. This leaves me with 2 small questions though.. For the $∇^ka_n$ could we sub in the 2 we previously got. And the second question being how would we address the $∇^ka_{n-1}$. That is the main part I am having trouble seeing now.

Comment: No, you can't sub in the 2. You need to find the formula for the second difference operator. The way to do it is that since the first difference gives you $a_n-a_{n-1}$, then now this is your new sequence and you apply it to that. It helps to know that this is linear, meaning, that you can apply it to each individual term. As for your second question, you shouldn't be troubled by the $n-1$. Whatever formula you have, you substitute $n$ with $n-1$. So for example, applying the first difference to the $a_{n-1}$ would give you $a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not quite sure that I follow. I am having trouble visualizing what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem you know that $\nabla a_n=2$ for all $n$, so $\nabla a_n-\nabla a_{n-1}=2-2=0$.

In the second you made an algebra error: $\nabla a_n=n^2-(n-1)^2=n^2-n^2+2n-1=2n-1$, not $-2n+1$. Note that this is an error that you should have caught: $-2n+1$ is clearly negative for $n\ge 1$, but $n^2-(n-1)^2$ can’t possibly be negative for $n\ge 1$.

To see how to deal with $\nabla a_{n-1}$, it may be helpful temporarily to introduce an auxiliary sequence: let $b_n=\nabla a_n=a_n-a_{n-1}$. Then

$$\nabla a_{n-1}=b_{n-1}=a_{n-1}-a_{(n-1)-1}=a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}\;.$$

Or you can simply realize that $\nabla a_k=a_k-a_{k-1}$ no matter what $k$ is, and when $k=n-1$, this becomes $\nabla a_{n-1}=a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$. At any rate, you now have

$$\nabla^2a_n=\nabla a_n-\nabla a_{n-1}=(2n-1)-\big(2(n-1)-1\big)\;,$$

and I’ll leave the cleaning up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for $a_n=n^2$ we have $∇a_n=a_n-a_{n-1}=n^2-(n-1)^2=n^2-n^2+2n-1=2n-1$. You had some signs wrong. As for the other, ${∇}^2a_n=∇(a_n-a_{n-1})=∇a_n-∇a_{n-1}=a_n-a_{n-1}-a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}=a_n-2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$. Applying this formula to $a_n=2n$, we get $∇^2a_n=2n-4(n-1)+2(n-2)=0$. This is the same as saying $∇ ∇a_n=∇2=0$, if this is the same as you mean by substituting the 2, then you were right, I misunderstood. You can do the other one in exactly this way.